# Oracle RegExp For Counting Words Occuring After a Character

Tags: sql, regex, count, words

I want to identify the number of words occurring after a comma, in a full name field in Oracle database table.

The name field contains format of "LAST, FIRST MIDDLE"
Some names may have up to 4 to 5 names, such as "DOE, JOHN A B"

For example, if the Name field = 'WILLIAMS JR, HANK' it would output 1 (for 1 word occurring after the comma.

If the Name field = 'DOE, JOHN A B' i want it to output 3.

I would like to use a regexp_count function to determine this count. 
I am using the following code to identify how many words exist in the field and would like to modify it to include this functionality:

> REGEXP_COUNT(REPLACE(fieldname, ',',', '), '[^]+')

It would likely have to remove the replace function in order to find the comma, but this was the best I could do so far.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the code as follows, which appears to be working as desired:

```
REGEXP_COUNT(fieldname, '[^ ]+', (INSTR(fieldname, ',')+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

`REGEXP_COUNT( fieldname, "\\w", INSTR(fieldname, ",")+1)`